# Use AngularJs on custom namespace and deleted window.angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, namespaces

For the website of my customer I use an Angular JS in version 1.5.7. On this website there is also an dynamic mechanism to integrate remote JS applications. This mechanism is loading first a configuration file with the information which additional scripts and stylesheets has to be loaded. One of the loaded appications is also using Angular JS but in version 1.3.9. This constellation results in an error that says there is a version incompatibility with the ngAnimate module.

My first solution was to move `window.angular` to `window.vendor.angular` and `delete window.angular` so the remote loaded Angular JS can work fine. The problem with this solution is, that Angular JS uses $window.angular at several locations.

Replacing `window.angular`and `$window.angular` is no real solution because I want to load AngularJS from a public CDN.

I am now looking for a solution where I can run Angular JS fully isolated or something like the `jQuery.noConflict()` from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple solution, not so fancy but it works. When the angularjs code loads, it stores an internal variable to store angularjs API. So, the solution is to load angularjs `1.5.7` and store it in a separate place (i.e., `window.angular1_5_7`) and clean the previous declaration (i.e., `window.angular = {};`) so then when the `1.3.9` gets loaded it won't get any conflicts.

```
<script>
  // angularjs stores window.angular internally when it is declared
  // var angular = window.angular || (window.angular = {}),
  window.angular1_5_7 = window.angular;
  window.angular = {};
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Then the `1.3.9` will bootstrap on the normal flow. You can use `ng-app` as well.

```
(function() {
  angular.module('app139', []);

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var element = angular.element(document.getElementById('app139'));
    angular.bootstrap(element, ['app139']);
  });
})();
```

And finally, when you bootstrap your `1.5.7` app, you can especify the stored version of angular `1.5.7` (i.e, `window.angular1_5_7`).

```
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('app157', []);

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var element = angular.element(document.getElementById('app157'));
    angular.bootstrap(element, ['app157']);
  });
})(window.angular1_5_7);
```

#### $window.angular and Proxy

It doesn't seem to be an issue because angularjs wouldn't cause conflicts when using `$window.angular` but if so, you could try this solution.

The only way I could find to solve the `$window.angular` issue is by using [ES6 proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to intermediate the `get` of the property `'angular'` resolving it as a decorator for the `$window` service. So when `$window` gets performed a `get` on a property called `angular` it will return `window.angular1_5_7` otherwise will return the normal object.

> **Unfortunately, it's not fully compatible with all browser [yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=proxy), it has been introduced on ES6 and there is no equivalent implementation on ES5.**

```
angular.module('app157', [])
    .config(function($provide) {

      $provide.decorator('$window', function $windowDecorator($delegate) {

        return new Proxy($delegate, {
          get: function(target, prop) {
            return prop == 'angular' ?
              window.angular1_5_7 :
              target[prop]
          }
        });
      });
    })
```

Full working snippet:

```js
// app 1.3.9 declarations
(function() {

  angular.module('app139', [])
    .run(function($rootScope, $window) {
      $rootScope.version = $window.angular.version;
    });

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {

    var element = angular.element(document.getElementById('app139'));
    angular.bootstrap(element, ['app139']);
  });

})();

// app 1.5.7 declarations
(function(angular) {

  angular.module('app157', [])
    .config(function($provide) {

      $provide.decorator('$window', function $windowDecorator($delegate) {

        return new Proxy($delegate, {
          get: function(target, prop) {
            return prop == 'angular' ?
              window.angular1_5_7 :
              target[prop]
          }
        });
      });
    })
    .run(function($rootScope, $window) {
      $rootScope.version = $window.angular.version;
    });

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {

    var element = angular.element(document.getElementById('app157'));
    angular.bootstrap(element, ['app157']);
  });

})(window.angular1_5_7);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script>
  // angularjs stores window.angular internally when it is declared
  // var angular = window.angular || (window.angular = {}),
  window.angular1_5_7 = window.angular;
  window.angular = {};
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>

<div id="app139">
  <h2>app 1.3.9</h2>
  <p>{{ version }}</p>
</div>

<div id="app157">
  <h2>app 1.5.7</h2>
  <p>{{ version }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem because `$window.angular.version` results in both modules in `{"full":"1.3.9","major":1,"minor":3,"dot":9,"codeName":"multidimensional-awareness"}` because the $WindowProvider returns the global window object.

Comment: @Sören Why you need `$window.angular` ? Also angular don't use `$window.angular` for things which would cause some conflict. I notice once that `$httpBackend` use it as well. But why this is a problem, where in your could it's causing a conflict?

Comment: @Sören Unfortunatelly there is no many solution for this but I could solve this by using Proxies, unfortunately, it's not compatible with all browser yet. I've updated my answer.